# Emit data to another node process

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 2 processes with `pm2`. My question is is it possible to emit some data from process A to process B?

I don't mean emit in same process, I mean emitting some data from

app1.js to app2.js

Comment: Maybe this helps? [Node.js Inter process communication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022539/node-js-inter-process-communication)

Comment: @FelixKling thank you, I will check it out